# Generated plugin registarant file won't generate in flutter after adding firebase packages

Tags: flutter

I am trying to initialise firebase to my flutter app and I have created firebase project in firebase console added the google-services.json file added all the dependencies, added all the required dependencies in app level and in android level build gradle file and tried everything: flutter clean, restart but Generated plugin registarant file won't generate. What should i do?

Comment: did you have permission to write in that folder? try to run commands with administration privileges

Comment: @Ruchit, How do i do that?

Comment: which os you are using?

Comment: @Ruchit I am using mac

Comment: use prefix your command with  sudo <your command here>, like sudo flutter pub get

Comment: @Ruchit, no doesn't work